# WCF service hosted in IIS with net.msmq binding creating trouble

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, msmq

I have a WCF Queue Listener service that picks messages from MSMQ. Its working fine no problem . But i dont know what IIS does, it creates wired problem many times. I can browse the service but when i refresh this it disappears. But again if i refresh after a second it comes back with no problem this problem is persisting.

I did a close monitoring of this. if i create a request within less than a second it fails to process this but if i request it after a second it comes fines.

I know this sounds stupid but until you have had this problem you will not understand.

Has anyone solved this issue before?

Comment: Are you hosting it in AppFabric? Have you checked System and Application event logs? What is "this" that you are refreshing and what is disappearing? If you are not using AppFabric it will take first call to activate the service. If service is idle (no incoming request) IIS will eventually shut down the process.

Comment: No i am hosting in IIS and i had a look at event logs and there is not meaningful information. I am browsing my site and refreshing it. I don't believe IIS puts the site in idle state for a second and resumes it. because if you browse after second it comes back. but if you do that before a second it disappears.its definitely something else because my idle timeout period is set to 60 minutes.

Comment: There are no errors in the event log related to .NET? How does the disappearance manifest itself (blank page, 500 error, DNS error)?

Comment: i know it sounds wired the site says "The resource cannot be found" and the event log says webhost failed to process a request, there was no channel actively listening at "service url" it is of course because i am trying to browse and it cannot process the request but doesn't say any other cause

Comment: One thing to try i setting up WCF diagnostics. [See here how](http://petarvucetin.me/blog/2013/02/setting-wcf-diagnostics-quickly/).

Comment: i already have got this configured and its producing Error.svclog file ni the server but its of no use since i cannot view this there is no microsoft sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened to me and we noticed that there were a lot of messages accumulated in the queue. 
Try cleaning the queue and restarting the msmq. This definitely works.